# Prettified restatements of existing answers

Tags: discussion

It's a bit irritating to see someone basically take the information from all the existing answers to a question and combine them into a new answer with pictures and nice formatting.

Comment: Can you site some specific examples?

Comment: Seems to be working as designed in that case. If the Answer: The Next Generation is better than the others, and more helpful for readers, let it get the votes. The point of the questions and answers is to help folks, not bicker over upvotes.

Answer (score 3):

## Creative Commons Licensing

Because all content on all [StackExchange sites](http://stackexchange.com/sites) is licensed under the [Creative Commons Attribution Share Alike](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) license, all content can be shared and/or remixed as long as proper [attribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attribution_(copyright)) is given.  This means users are well within their rights to alter, transform, or build upon *your* work.

## What about edits?

While some users may choose to edit existing answers, there is no reason a better formatted answer that combines multiple answers should not be allowed.

Comment: this isn't properly attributed :P

Comment: @waxeagle My lawyer says I've made enough changes to not warrant attribution.

Answer (score 2):

All Stack Exchange content is licensed under the CC-By-SA content license.

That means that, provided that attribution is given, it's perfectly legal and acceptable for someone to take other answers and make them better, or "prettify and restate" them.

While editing is often the preferable case, there is no reason that a better formatted answer, or an answer that synthesizes multiple answers should be prohibited.

The problem case with answer restatements is when the restatement is of *lower* quality than the original answer.